# Tkinter button activates when Program Runs - Lambda not working

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class LoginGUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Login")

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding = "3 3 12 12")
        self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.mainframe.grid(sticky=("N, W, E, S"))

        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text = "Login", font = (20)).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text = "Username: ").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text = "Password: ").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

        self.user = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()

        self.user_entry = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, width=10, textvariable = self.user)
        self.user_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

        self.password_entry = ttk.Entry(self.mainframe, show = "*", width=10, textvariable = self.password)
        self.password_entry.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

        #ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text = "Login", command = testLogin()).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text = "Register").grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))

        self.valid = ""

        ttk.Label(self.mainframe, textvariable = self.valid).grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=(W, E))

        self.user_entry.focus()

    def testLogin(self, usr):
        if (self.user == usr.getUser()) and (self.password == usr.getPass()):
            self.valid = "Correct!"
            messagebox.showinfo("Login Confirmation", self.valid)

        else:
            self.valid = "Incorrect!"
            messagebox.showinfo("Login Confirmation", self.valid)

class Credentials:
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = "User"
        self.password = "Pass123"

    def getUser(self):
        return self.username

    def getPass(self):
        return self.password


def main():
    root = Tk()
    login = LoginGUI(root)

    usr1 = Credentials()
    ttk.Button(login.mainframe, text = "Login", command=lambda: login.testLogin(usr1)).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=(W, E))

    root.bind('<Return>', login.testLogin(usr1))

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

I'm still learning GUI programming and I made this as a test just to see if I could make a Login screen for fun. I understand it is pretty rough and definitely needs work.

The Problem I have is, it opens the message box immediately when the program runs instead of when I click the Login button. Why?

I've seen similar questions with people having the same problem but the Lambda solution that worked for them does not work for me, unless I am doing it wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the error, I replaced the `lambda : testLogin(user)` by a `lambda : print('foo')`. Command still casted but nothing printed...
Search in file for `testLogin` and eureka! Your binding requires a lambda too, you are calling test in it for instance.

Additionally, the correct line is :

```
root.bind('<Return>', lambda x : login.testLogin(usr1))
```

It is required to add a lambda parameter as the event binded will be passed as parameter.

Have fun with Tk and ttk ;)

Arthur.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered ^^ And it was a pleasur, I like Tkinter!